# Эмулятор в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, эмулятор, android

Всем привет!

Только начал совершать первые шаги по изучение Android и сразу же появились проблемы.
При попытке создать первый эмулятор через Android Studio в AVD Manager появляется сообщение

> "Failed to load" в разделе Actions.

Естественно, через кнопку Run оно тоже не запускается и советует "что-то исправить". Что посоветуете?

Comment: не поленитесь, скачайте Genymotion, он разительно шустрее

Comment: Возможно Вы выделили мало оперативной памяти на эмулятор, рекомендуемый ее размер >1г.

Answer (score 2):

Стандартный эмулятор Андроида убог. Рекомендую использовать сторонние, например, [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/).